# How to replace json value with list of items based on the key

Tags: python, json

How do I replace the json_object's blookup with blookup_values based on the ID's in the json blookup. I tried the below code by removing the ID's which are not present in the json_object['blookup']. The below code doesn't work. Could anyone please help.

```
blookup_values = [
{
    "id":"123",
    "name":"abc",
    "date":"somedate",
    "time":"sometime"
},
{
    "id":"456",
    "name":"def",
    "date":"somedate",
    "time":"sometime"
},
{
    "id":"789",
    "name":"ghi",
    "date":"somedate",
    "time":"sometime"
},
{
    "id":"9999",
    "name":"mmmmmm",
    "date":"somedate",
    "time":"sometime"
},
{
    "id":"8888",
    "name":"nnnnnn",
    "date":"somedate",
    "time":"sometime"
}
]

json_object = {
"id":"id_value",
"blookup": [{
    "id":"123",
    "type":"dddd"
},
    {
        "id":"456",
        "type":"eeeee"
    }
]
}
```

**Code**

```
result = [obj for obj in blookup_values if obj['id'] != json_object['blookup']]
```

**Expected result**

```
result = {
"id":"id_value",
"blookup": [{
    "id":"123",
    "name":"abc",
    "date":"somedate",
    "time":"sometime"
},
    {
        "id":"456",
        "name":"def",
        "date":"somedate",
        "time":"sometime"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: These are dictionaries and lists. The fact that they were created from JSON is irrelevant once you start processing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the id key from the json_object dictionaries:

```
result = [obj for obj in blookup_values if obj['id'] in [i["id"] for i in json_object['blookup']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert `blookup_values` into a dictionary keyed by `id`. Then you can replace `json_object['blookup']` with a list comprehension made from this.

```
blookup_dict = {value['id']: value for value in blookup_values}
json_object['blookup'] = [blookup_dict[item['id']] for item in json_object['blookup']]
```

Comment: I am getting an error with one of the ID.

Comment: Is there an ID in `blookup` that isn't in `blookup_values`? If so, what do you want in the result?

Comment: No, blookup_values is a collection of all the IDs and blookup has only few from blookup_values.

Comment: What was the error?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do but what I gather is that you want to get the objects in `blookup` that do not have any of the same `id`s as the objects in json_objects. Is that correct?

Try to first get the id values of each object in `json_object['blookup']`. For example:

```py
json_object_ids = [obj['id'] for obj in json_object['blookup']]
```

Next, filter the objects in `blookup` by slightly altering your list comprehension:

```py
result = [obj for obj in blookup_values if obj['id'] not in json_object_ids]
```

The output would look something like this:

```py
[{'id': '789', 'name': 'ghi', 'date': 'somedate', 'time': 
'sometime'}, {'id': '9999', 'name': 'mmmmmm', 'date': 'som
edate', 'time': 'sometime'}, {'id': '8888', 'name': 'nnnnn
n', 'date': 'somedate', 'time': 'sometime'}]
```